# GA v4 in a React Vite project

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, vite

What's the best way to add Google Analytics to a Vite React project? I have added the gtag.js script into the `index.html` file within the Vite project. It does track users in Real Time but doesn't seem to track anything else. This makes me think the code should be in `App.jsx` instead...

Because when I go to GA I am getting the message saying there is No data received from my website yet.

I have looked into `react-ga` but this seems to only work with `UA-XXX` tags where as I am using GA v4 which uses IDs of `G-XXXX`

Has anyone added a v4 GA tag into a React project?

### Update

Just found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4

This is how I have it now...

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4'
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
import Footer from './components/base/Footer'
import Header from './components/base/Header'
import Form from './components/Form'
import Table from './components/Table'

ReactGA.initialize('G-XXXXXXX')
ReactGA.send('pageview')

function App() {
  return (
    ...
```

But still getting the message "No data received from your website yet." in GA

Comment: how long did you wait.  It takes a while for the data to be procesesd.

Comment: clearly not long enough...lol Is the implementation correct? Ill hit the gym then hopefully it will be working.

Comment: its normally 24 / 48 hours but if its a new ga account it can take a few days before it starts recording data.

Comment: Lovely thanks...just got back from the gym and it's all working as intended. Thanks for the extra info

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use a vite plugin for that. Currently [Vite-plugin-radar](https://github.com/stafyniaksacha/vite-plugin-radar) is available and it supports 7+ analytics providers ( Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager, Facebook Pixel, Linkedin Insight, Yandex Metrica, Baidu Tongji and Microsoft Advertising)

Another advantage with vite plugins is that mostly they are framework agnostic, so you can use them with Vue, React, Svelte or other vite supported frameworks.

Comment: ah good to know thats :)